# Как сделать обработку нажатия на какой-либо тег с конкретным классом?

Tags: javascript, html

К примеру, у нас есть какой-то `div`, при нажатии на ссылку которого происходит смена класса в другом диве:

```js
function active(element) {
  //Очищаем все уже нажатые элементы
  for (var i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    var clear = document.getElementById("tab_" + i);
    clear.className = "cont" + i;
  }
  //Присваиваем новый класс нажатому элементу
  var block = document.getElementById("tab_" + element);
  if (block.className == "cont" + element) {
    block.className = "cont" + element + " is_active";
  }
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#" onclick="active('1');">Смени меня</a></div>
<div><a href="#" onclick="active('2');">Смени меня</a></div>
<div id="tab_1" class="cont1 is_active">
  <p>Первый див</p>
</div>
<div id="tab_2" class="cont2">
  <p>Второй див</p>
</div>
```

Из кода видно, что функция `active` вызывается при нажатии на конкретную ссылку через `onclick`. Но как сделать вызов этой функции, чтобы в атрибутах стоял только `id`? Как должен измениться JS, кроме того, что он станет каким-то "пассивным" обработчиком? Могу ошибаться в формулировке.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, суть совершенно непонятна.

Comment: @Igor, если коротко, то я просто хотел убрать _onclick_ внутри тегов, и чтобы обработка нажатия происходила как-то иначе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Может слегка костыльно, но написал на коленке.**

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("a")].forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let foo = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
      if (foo[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        foo[i].classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        foo[index].classList.add("active");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click me 1</a>
<a href="#">Click me 2</a>

<p>Some text 1</p>
<p>Some text 2</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так, наверное, попытался не трогать вашу оригинальную функцию `active(element)`

```js
function active(element) {
  //Очищаем все уже нажатые элементы
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var clear = document.getElementById("tab_" + i);
    clear.className = "cont" + i;
  }
  //Присваиваем новый класс нажатому элементу
  var block = document.getElementById("tab_" + element);
  if (block.className == "cont" + element) {
    block.className = "cont" + element + " is_active";
  }
}

[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.clickable'))
  .forEach((el, i) => el.onclick = active.bind(null, i+1));
```

```css
.is_active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#" class='clickable'>Смени меня</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class='clickable'>Смени меня</a></div>
<div id="tab_1" class="cont1 is_active">
  <p>Первый див</p>
</div>
<div id="tab_2" class="cont2">
  <p>Второй див</p>
</div>
```